# iOS Swift Variable are not accessible in functions

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Im doing this app and When I call a variable outside a function it won't recognize it as shown bellow

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var monsterImg: MonsterAnimation!

@IBOutlet weak var heartImg: DragImages!

@IBOutlet weak var foodImg: DragImages!

// Skulls on Top Board
@IBOutlet weak var penalty1Img: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var penalty2Img: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var penalty3Img: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Skulls Alpha Manipulation
    let DIM_ALPHA: CGFloat = 0.2
    let OPAQUE: CGFloat = 1.0
    let MAX_PENALTIES = 3

    var penalties = 0 // VARIABLE NOT ABLE TO BE SEEN IN FUNCTION ALSO ABOVE ^^^

    foodImg.dropTarget = monsterImg
    heartImg.dropTarget = monsterImg

    // Skulls Alpha Initalzation
    penalty1Img.alpha = DIM_ALPHA
    penalty2Img.alpha = DIM_ALPHA
    penalty3Img.alpha = DIM_ALPHA

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "itemDroppedOnCharacter:", name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)

}

func itemDroppedOnCharacter(notif: AnyObject) {

}

func startSkullTimer() {
    var skullTimer: NSTimer!

    if skullTimer != nil {
        skullTimer.invalidate()
    }

    skullTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: "changeGameState", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func changeGameState() {

    penalties++ // HERE IT"S NOT ABLE TO SEE THE VARIABLE ABOVE

}
```

But When I put it inside the function it works but then the other variables and things don't recognize it because its in the function. How do I fix this so the function will recognize the Variables out side it?

Comment: scope of your variable is clearly only inside `viewDidLoad` function. Just declare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your variables outside of `viewDidLoad()` together with your IBOutlets.

If you want to give them initial values you can do it either direct when declaring or just give a type and set the value again in `viewDidLoad()`

For more information on the topic of access control, read up on the Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You are facing the issue of "scope". A variable defined in an inner scope like a function is only accessible inside that inner scope (the function). Once you exit the function, the variable "goes out of scope" and is forgotten.

Think of scope as groups of circles. A variable defined in a circle (scope) is only visible inside that circle. Circles inside a larger circle have access to the variables defined in the outer circle. (Inner scope has access to enclosing scope.)

Functions have a "containing scope" in which they are defined. If a function is an instance method of a class, then it has access to instance variables from the object.

Thus, if you need two functions to both have access to the same variable, that variable needs to be in a common, outer scope. (Or if one function calls the other you can pass the value as a parameter.) Again, for instance methods, it might make sense to make the *value* that both functions need an instance variable of the class.

In your case, these are instance methods of a view controller, so you just need to make your `penalties` variable an instance variable of your view controller. You do that by moving it's declaration outside of the function and into the top part of the declaration of your `ViewController` class.